# How to evenly match event clicks and goals in Google Analytics?

Tags: google-analytics, google-tag-manager

I have Google Tag Manager firing an event with a value of "1" every time a specific type of link is clicked. For the purpose of this questions, let's say there are **two** types of links. When one type is clicked it gets an Event Action "A" and when the other type is clicked it gets an Event Action "B". In Google Analytics I want to set different values based on whether it's Event Action "A" or Event Action "B" by using Goal Completions for each event trigger.

Here is how the data is currently coming in:
[image: event value versus goal completions]

The event condition is set up as follows:
[image: event conditions]

The labels of the events are the URLs being clicked, so the counts can increment, which I believe is the source of the discrepancy. I'm wondering how I can get the Goal Completions to match up 1:1 with the Event Values.

Comment: Why each Action A and Action B have 2 lines in the first screenshot?

Comment: They both have text that would count as "Action A" (such as, if the category contains "dogs" then it's Action A. There might be 2 or 3 types of dog clicks, but they're all worth the same amount.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot match the goal conversion value 1:1 with event values. This is because the goal is counted only once per session while event clicks can be counted multiple times.
So for the above goal setting, only 1 goal conversion will be fired for this event irrespective of how many different labels you have in event label.

Hope this helps.

Comment: That makes sense. Thanks for clarifying!